# CreateWindowEx called on button click fails

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to create a dialog window from button window click in WM_COMMAND of main window procedure.

```
case WM_CREATE: 
            hwndRegister = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Register"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 100, 50, hwnd, (HMENU)REGISTER_WINDOW, NULL, NULL);
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
            {
                case REGISTER_WINDOW:
                    DisplayRegisterDialog(hwndRegister);
                    break;
            }
            break;
```

If that hwndRegister is clicked, It should pop up new dialog window defined and registered in another cpp file.

```
CONST wchar_t DIALOG_WINDOW_NAME[] = L"DialogClass";
void RegisterDialog(HINSTANCE hInstance) 
{
    WNDCLASS dialogBox = { };

    dialogBox.lpfnWndProc = DialogProc;
    dialogBox.lpszClassName = DIALOG_WINDOW_NAME;
    dialogBox.hInstance = hInstance;
    dialogBox.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClass(&dialogBox);
}

void DisplayRegisterDialog(HWND hwnd) 
{
    if (!hwnd) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation faile", L"WINDOW CREATION FAILED", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    HWND hwndDialogWindow = CreateWindowEx(0, DIALOG_WINDOW_NAME, L"Register User", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 200, 200, hwnd, (HMENU)DIALOG_REGISTER_WINDOW, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I'm getting the instance to register dialog from winapi winmain of main application.

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
RegisterDialog(hInstance);
}
```

For now I don't get any visible error thrown and the program runs smoothly. However, The dialog window is not created nor an error is thrown.
Edit -
Dialog procedure implementation:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I'd also like to note after following IInspectable advice on error checking manually. I did this if window is being registered

```
if (RegisterClass(&dialogBox) == 0) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Dialog window registration failed", L"Error", 0);
        throw GetLastError();
    }
```

This code throws the exception of Microsoft C++ exception: unsigned long at memory location 0x0078F828.

EDIT 2-
Alright. I've finally found the problem with error code 1410 Class already exists. I have difference names for these windows class. Is it because of hInstance ?

Comment: I tend to have similar problems and most of them relate to what the window procedure  returns to the `WM_CREATE` message. What is the code of your `DialogProc`?
From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create :
"If an application processes this message, it should return zero to continue creation of the window. If the application returns –1, the window is destroyed and the CreateWindowEx or CreateWindow function returns a `NULL` handle."
Did you check that `hwndDialogWindow` is `NULL`?

Comment: Another point that's slightly off-topic: What you create is another main ("overlapped") window, not a dialog. You might want to create your dialog as a resource and use `DialogBox`.

Comment: Hy, @Iziminza Thank you for your prompt reply. That dialogProc is the procedure for dialog window to be created for now, I have only defined the WM_CLOSE in it. Create and command is called from main window procedure and Create only creates the register window button.

Comment: Hy, I had checked the dialog box and I don't think I can manipulate the box as I wish. My dialog box should contain atleast 2 input boxes for name and passwod and button to submit. Is that possible with dialog box ?

Comment: Of course it is! You have to create a dialog box resource and add those controls.

Comment: The Windows API is a C interface. Errors aren't *"thrown"* at you. You will have to discover error conditions manually. `RegisterClass` can fail but the code chooses to ignore its return value. `CreateWindow` can fail as well but the code chooses to not observe an error condition. Start by adding code that observes errors.

Comment: I created a simple dialog resource script that you should be able to open: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gsj0ph6v1quqic/RegisterDialog.rc?dl=0

Comment: Why are you setting the button's `HWND` as the owner window for an overlapped dialog?

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau this dialog window is called after the button is clicked. Thus I set it as owner. Is that a wrong approach ?

Comment: @ShanksLimbu yes, it is a very wrong approach. If you assign any owner at all, it should be the window that owns the button, not the button itself. You should read [Window Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features), in particular [Owned Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Your function `DialogProc` is actually a normal window procedure, not a dialog procedure, so you have to pass unhandled messages to `DefWindowProc`, like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc /*misnomer!*/(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        MessageBox(hwnd, L"Test", L"Test", 0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // important!!
}
```

If you write `return 0;` instead, the window will be destroyed immediately after it returns from the call with `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: HI @Iziminza Thank you but I already had this in place and I'm still facing the problem.

Comment: @ShanksLimbu please edit your question to include a [mcve] showing how your 
`DialogProc()` is actually implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to HMENU set in hwndDialogWindow. It had to be null. Also about 1410 error. I am confused about it as well. The code is

```
RegisterClass(&dialogBox);
if (RegisterClass(&dialogBox) == 0) {
        int nresult = GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Dialog window registration failed", L"Error", 0);
    }
```

I don't know how the above code produces 1410 error. I remove the first line to register and the error went away.

Also Thank you to RemyLebeau for pointing out the wrong approach, Inspectable for the advice on manually checking error which was tremendously helpful and Iziminza for dialog rss script which I'll use for other button.

Comment: Error 1410 is `ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS`. Hardly surprising, since you are trying to register **exactly the same class** twice. In a row. It's unclear what you are trying to do here, though you would probably be *far* better off getting your hands on some learning material for the Windows API (like Petzold's "Programming Windows - 5th Ed."). Guessing won't be a sustainable, effective, or efficient approach.

Comment: The HMENU you pass does not have to be `NULL`, but if it's not, it has to be a menu *handle*, not a menu resource identifier. This means that you have to load it with the `LoadMenu` function first.